# WebDriverError: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (330, 367) even after using EC.elementToBeClickable

Tags: protractor

I am writing test cases in protractor using chromedriver

I have a link which when clicked gives an overlay div pop up where I can enter few details and Add details. After adding the details again the main page and link is visible. But when I am trying to click on the main link second time I am getting

WebDriverError: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (330, 367). Other element would receive the click:

I tried using the below code still issue is not resolved

```
    browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(link)).then(function(){
        link.click().then(function(){
            browser.sleep(3000).should.notify(next);
        });
    });
```

Can someone please help

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this in my application before, Once you close the pop-up you have to wait for the window closing animation to finish. Your flow should be something like below

```
 browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(link),5000)
//Fill the pop-up
 element(by.css('.textArea')).sendKeys('jhghaskjdhkjasd')
//close the pop-up
element(by.css('.close')).click()
//wait for the pop-up to close
browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(element(by.css('.pop-up'))),5000)
```

Also as a side point, you don't need to chain all webdriverJs promises.They are already placed in queue using Protractor control flow

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But for some test cases I am getting                      Error: Step timed out after 600000 milliseconds
          at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:92:15)        after i click on add button  and wait for popup to disappear . Any guess why it is happening so

Comment: Also for some testcases the div is said to be not found NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By(css selector, .ngdialog-overlay)